# Open in.. for html-pages (in Safari)

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, ios4, safari

I was wondering if I could create an app which supports opening .html-pages.

For example, if the app supports .pdf, when opening a .pdf, a small gray box appears with the button "Open in myApp". Can I get something like this, but then for a webpage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmm you are talking about `UIDocumentInteractionController` then.
Implement `UIDocumentInteractionControllerDelegate` in your UIViewController

```
- (UIViewController *)documentInteractionControllerViewControllerForPreview:(UIDocumentInteractionController *)controller { return self; }
- (UIView *)documentInteractionControllerViewForPreview:(UIDocumentInteractionController *)controller { return self.view; }
- (CGRect)documentInteractionControllerRectForPreview:(UIDocumentInteractionController *)controller { return self.view.frame; }
```

Then add a button to the navigation bar to popup the options box:

```
// example: opening a .html file
NSString *index = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"index" ofType:@"html"];

// self.controller is a UIDocumentInteractionController ivar
self.controller = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:fileToOpen]];
self.controller.delegate = self;
CGRect rect = self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame;
rect.size = CGSizeMake(1500.0f, 40.0f); // move the box right down under the button
[self.controller presentOptionsMenuFromRect:rect inView:self.view animated:YES];
```

A list of the applications supporting a particular document should appear. If you didn't register your app to support a type of document you still get the option "QuickLook". All this happens on whatever application is interacting with the file (since the files themselves are not exposed on the UI).

Comment: The gray rectangle shows up automatically, because the app has the support for .pdf-files (adapted in the bundle). It's nothing I've programmed, iOS shows the gray box with the option to open it in my app. At that time, my app has possibly not even started yet. I'd like to have the same for .html-files